# Does a lots of update in an ElasticSearch index can cause issues?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm concerned about doing a lot of update in an ES INDEX.
I have the following index :

- 15M (millions) of documents
- 3GB
- 3 shards
- heap size of 6GB
- 1 master and 2 replicas

This index contains ~300k products.
A snapshot of a product is :

```
"_source": { - 
      "row_id": "123456",
      "entity_id": "123456",
      "attribute_set_id": "1000",
      "type_id": "simple",
      "sku": "10000",
      "created_at": "2022-10-27 15:59:34",
      "updated_at": "2022-12-12 18:28:38",
      "visibility": "4",
      "etc..."
      "store_prices": [ - 
        { - 
          "store_prices_id": 10000,
          "product_id": 123456,
          "store": 1,
          "type": "PRO"
          "visibility": 1,
          "label": "In Stock",
          "price": "12.0000",
          "special_price": "10.0000"
          etc... about 20 mores informations
        },
        { - 
          "store_prices_id": 10001,
          "product_id": 123456,
          "store": 1,
          "type": "NOT_PRO"
          "visibility": 1,
          "label": "In stock",
          "price": "11.0000",
          "special_price": "9.0000"
          etc... about 20 mores informations
        },
        etc... I have 40 stores meaning 40 times the previous couple of "PRO" / "NOT_PRO"
}
```

As said previously there is ~300k product and 40 stores (we could consider 80 with "PRO" / "NOT PRO") per product.
Then we receive a lot of "store_prices" update.
Right now, we re-create our index from time to time to have updated prices.
But we would like fresher prices displayed.

One update equals to one "store_prices" that has a change (the price, special_price or one of the 20 other informations has a change).
However, I think I can't really distinguish what is the real modification so the update would be an entire "stores_prices_id" and not only the data that has really changed in this peculiar "stores_prices_id".

**Let's say that at 1:00 pm we receive 1M (million) of "store_prices" in a queue.
It is wise (or even possible) to smash this index over and over to update the "store_prices" and decrease this queue until it's done (the faster the better) ?**

If is possible to update a nested field like that using the "store_prices_id" as a match ?

If we do no bulk update, it means that we have made 1 millions of update.
If we use bulk update, I think it means that we have made 1 millions of update but bulked by a batch_size of X.
Lastly, **there would be 20 processes unstacking the queue**, meaning we could potentially have at the same time an update on the same product.

Could it make the index crash or things like that ?
Also, **the index is obviously used during the course of the day**, could it create lags / deadlocks ?

FYI, I did some tests to update a field that is not nested and is a float, it takes 1800 seconds (30 minutes) for 130k products meaning 14ms per product with bulked update of 1000. This test was done by a single process.

Thank you in advance :) !

Comment: why do you have them all in a single document per product? why not just have multiple, flatter documents with a timestamp and then use something like top hits to get the latest document?